# Можно ли добавить все объекты класса в массив одним разом?

Tags: java

Подскажите, существует ли способ записать все объекты Класса в массив одним методом?
После каждого созданного объекта руками писать `list.add` как то совсем кажется не правильным.

```java
ArrayList<Human> humans = new ArrayList();
        Human grandpa1 = new Human("Ded1", true, 99);
        Human grandma1 = new Human("Ba1", false, 90);
        Human grandpa2 = new Human("Ded2", true, 98);
        Human grandma2 = new Human("Ba2", false, 91);
        Human father = new Human("Pa", true, 41, grandpa1, grandma1);
        Human mother = new Human("Ma", false, 35, grandpa2, grandma2);
        Human kid1 = new Human("Kid1", true, 8, father, mother);
        Human kid2 = new Human("Kid2", false, 13, father, mother);
        Human kid3 = new Human("Kid3", true, 5, father, mother);
        humans.add(grandpa1);
        humans.add(grandma1);
        humans.add(grandpa2);
        humans.add(grandma2);
        humans.add(father);
        humans.add(mother);
        humans.add(kid1);
        humans.add(kid2);
        humans.add(kid3);
```

Comment: есть способы из разряда вредные советы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это: http://lib.ru/ANEKDOTY/osterwred.txt?

Comment: `humans.add(new Human("Ded1", true, 99));` - пробовали?

Comment: @Tsyklop Думаю, ему нужны отдельно мамы, отдельно папы. Поэтому рациональней хранить их в массивах, а если понадобиться, вызывать статический метод

Comment: @Miron массивы не так функциональны как коллекции. Для них придется писать код для работы с ними который уже есть в коллекция. Иными словами - изобретать велосипед. С тем же успехом можно иметь разные коллекции.

Comment: @Tsyklop вы правы, но как я понял, он знает точный состав семьи. Или нет?.. Уточню в ответе

Comment: @Miron состав семьи определяется наличием соответствующих аргуметов при создании объекта, в принципе, в коллекции могут быть представители нескольких семей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прописать добавление в конструктор, тогда объект будет сразу залетать в лист, но не нужно этого делать.

Лучше создать метод в классе Human вроде

```
public Human addToList(ArrayList<Human> humanList) {
   humanList.add(this);
   return this;
}
```

Тогда можно будет просто писать

```
ArrayList<Human> humans = new ArrayList();
Human grandpa1 = new Human("Ded1", true, 99).addToList(humans);
...
```

Другой вариант – создать отдельный класс-структуру вроде

```
class HumanList {
    private ArrayList humans = new ArrayList<>();
    public Human add(Human human){
        humans.add(human);
        return human;
    }
    public ArrayList getHumans(){
        return humans;
    } 
}
```

Тогда добавление будет выглядеть как

```
HumanList humans = new HumanList();
Human grandpa1 = humans.add(new Human("Ded1", true, 99));
…
```

И использование листа

```
humans.getHumans();
```

Мне кажется, что второй вариант лучше, т.к. оставляет больше свободы для маневра. Например, можно сделать его синглтоном или напихать туда еще методов для управления собранными human-ами…
Но тут уж все от задачи зависит.

Comment: Сильно спорить не буду, т.к. этот ответ принят, но... Так никто не делает. Передавать в метод класса коллекцию и говорить, мол "добавь себя сюда" - это совсем неправильно. Второй вариант вообще намного лучше, но слишком запутан. Мы в параметрах метода создаем объект, который этим же методом возвращаем. Да, это уменьшает к-во строк, но очевидность такого кода сомнительная. Я бы оставил метод add() возвращающим результат вставки в лист, т.е. boolean. Или вообще void

Comment: Да, оно так логичнее. Просто вопрос был, как я понял продиктован желанием сократить код...

Answer (score 1):

Вначале создаете все нужные объекты, а потом лист с конструктором, который принимает другой лист:

```java
ArrayList<Human> humans = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(grandpa1, grandma1 /*, и т.д. */));
```

Comment: Извините, а что значит аргумент `итд...`?

Comment: Извиняю. Не надо умничать.

Comment: Если вас обидел мой комментарий, отметьте его тревогой как "недружелюбный" или поясните, почему вы его так восприняли. Не стоит отвечать в язвительном тоне.

Comment: Я не обижаюсь ни в коем случае. Просто уверен, что даже нлвичек в джаве понял бы что означает аргумент `итд...`, не говоря уже о таких опытных членах сообщества как Вы...

Comment: Не могу разделить вашу уверенность, я, например не понял. Вы конечно можете откатить правку как автор, но мне кажется, что если предложенный код компилируется, то всегда понятней.

Comment: Я раньше отвечал полностью рабочим кодом, после чего все кидались тапками, что все на блюдечке предоставляют и топикстартер даже думать не должен. Поэтому теперь я оставляю  поле для деятельности

Comment: Может вы путаете "полностью рабочий код" и "минимальный рабочий пример"? Первое да, не приветствуется. Если всё таки тапки летели за последнее, дайте ссылку на ответ, посмотреть интересно.